# Remove space in the beginning of the page

Tags: spacing, newlfm

In fact, I want tor remove the space in the beginning of the page, here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,stdletter,orderfromtodate,sigleft]{newlfm}
\usepackage{blindtext, xfrac}
\setlength\parindent{1cm}
\newlfmP{dateskipbefore=50pt}
\newlfmP{sigsize=50pt}
\newlfmP{sigskipbefore=50pt}
\newlfmP{Headlinewd=0pt,Footlinewd=0pt}
\date{}
\usepackage{etoolbox} \makeatletter \patchcmd{\@zfancyhead}{\fancy@reset} 
{\f@nch@reset}{}{} \patchcmd{\@set@em@up}{\f@ncyolh}{\f@nch@olh}{}{} 
\patchcmd{\@set@em@up}{\f@ncyolh}{\f@nch@olh}{}{} \patchcmd{\@set@em@up} 
{\f@ncyorh}{\f@nch@orh}{}{} \makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}
\blindtext
\Blindtext

\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: uses the `article` class instead of the `newlfm` class which is a derivative of the `letter` class.

Comment: I want to reduce the spacing with that newlfm class